# Which namespace is used for xsl:element when name is an attribute value template

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to understand how xsl:element works properly and I have this test transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <xsl:template match="test">
        <output>
            <test1/>
            <xsl:element name="test2"/>
            <xsl:variable name="three" select="3"/>
            <xsl:element name="test{$three}"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test/>
```

I get this result using xsltproc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<output xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <test1/>
    <test2/>
    <test3 xmlns=""/>
</output>
```

Why is the test3 node not in the same namespace as test1 and test2?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your result; xsltproc (compiled against libxml 20703, libxslt 10124, and libexslt 813) gives me test3 in the same namespace as the others.  Which version of xsltproc are you using?

Comment: Using libxml 20900, libxslt 10127 and libexslt 816
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20900, libxslt 10127 and libexslt 816
libxslt 10127 was compiled against libxml 20900
libexslt 816 was compiled against libxml 20900

Comment: So this might be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio and getting it to apply the XSLT I get the below (formatted for readability),   so I would say it is a bug in xsltproc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<output xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <test1 />
  <test2 />
  <test3 />
</output>
```